# Параметр obfuscation_level_support в php

Tags: php

Какой значения может принимать параметр `zend_loader.obfuscation_level_support` в файле `php.ini` и где про это можно прочитать? И какой смысл самого параметра?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Параметр `zend_loader.obfuscation_level_support` используется в модуле Zend loader, который запускает файлы скомпилированные Zend Guard, документацию которого и нужно почитать.

`obfuscation_level_support` - уровень обфускации кода, генерируемого Zend Guard.

Возможные значения:

- 0 - нет обфускации
- 1 - Encoding Only, только компиляция в бинарник
- 2 - Basic, модификация перененных
- 3 - Strong, модификация имен классов и функций